# I have code that copies sheets, need help to add condition that sheet name must be in range

Tags: vba, excel

I have some great code I found on this site that works well but i'm new to vba and unsure, need to add criteria that the sheet name created appears in named range "WeekEnd"

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("MASTER")
    Dim newws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, newname
    Dim query As Long, xst As Boolean, info As String

retry:
    xst = False
    newname = Application.InputBox("Enter new week ending date in YYMMDD format:", info, , , , , , 2)
    If newname = "False" Then Exit Sub

    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If sh.Name = newname Then
            xst = True: Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Len(newname) = 0 Or xst = True Then
        info = "Sheet name is invalid. Please retry."
        GoTo retry
    End If

    ws.Copy after:=ws: Set newws = ActiveSheet: newws.Name = newname
End Sub
```

Comment: It helps to point out what condition you are currently trying, that way new VBA people can understand better where the problem is.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by *"that the sheet name created appears in named range "WeekEnd""*. Please give more details about what your actual goal is here.

Comment: You will want to make sure that the names being used don't contain any invalid characters and doesn't exceed the max character count.  See this site for a great little function: http://codevba.com/excel/valid_sheet_name.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If Len(newname) = 0 Or xst = True Or _
  IsError(Application.Match(newname, Range("WeekEnd"), 0)) Then
```

If there no match for the sheet name in the named range then `Match()` returns an error, which is checked for using `IsError()`

Comment: Thanks Tim you understand exactly what I need but sorry I'm really new and making a basic error, can you post code as complete please i'm getting compile error syntax

Comment: Thanks I worked it out just missing a bracket. appreciate the help!!